# Replace old div content with new in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am developing video Player in which XML is my playlist.
Here is code:

```
$crxml=file_get_contents('http://spoti.com/latest.xml/?lang=en');    
$rss=new SimpleXMLElement($crxml);
$playlistitem=1;
   foreach($rss->channel->item as $post)
    {   
    if($playlistitem<=8)
    {    
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li class="xtitle">'.$post->title.'</li>';
    echo '<li class="xdesc">'.$post->description.'</li>';    
    $dc=$post->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
    echo '<li class="xthumb">'.$dc->thumbnail->attributes()->url.'</li>';
    echo '<li class="xpreview">'.$dc->thumbnail->attributes()->url.'</li>'; 
    echo '<li class="xsources_mp4">'.$dc->content->attributes()->url.'</li>';
    $dc->content->attributes()->url=preg_replace('/.mp4/','.webm',$dc->content-attributes()->url);
     echo '<li class="xsources_webm">'.$dc->content->attributes()->url.'</li>';
     echo '</ul>';
    $playlistitem++;
     }
```

I  want to replace the old content with new content when user click on Language all the entries replace with new entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#lang').change(function() {
$.post('player_xml.php', {lang: $(this).val()}, function(data) {
    $('#xplaylist').html(data);

        $lang =strtolower( issset($_GET['lang'] ) ? $_GET['lang']:'en');
     $crxml=file_get_contents('http://spoti.com/latest.xml/?lang='. $lang); 
    $rss=new SimpleXMLElement($crxml);
      $playlistitem=1;
      foreach($rss->channel->item as $post)       
     if($playlistitem<=8)        
echo '<ul>';
echo '<li class="xtitle">'.$post->title.'</li>';
echo '<li class="xdesc">'.$post->description.'</li>';    
$dc=$post->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
echo '<li class="xthumb">'.$dc->thumbnail->attributes()->url.'</li>';
echo '<li class="xpreview">'.$dc->thumbnail->attributes()->url.'</li>'; 
echo '<li class="xsources_mp4">'.$dc->content->attributes()->url.'</li>';
$dc->content->attributes()->url=preg_replace('/.mp4/','.webm',$dc->content-attributes()->url);
 echo '<li class="xsources_webm">'.$dc->content->attributes()->url.'</li>';
 echo '</ul>';
$playlistitem++;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, once the page loads, the PHP has done its job and can do no more.

If you want to change something once the page has loaded, you should try something like jquery:

```
<script>
  $("Class_or_ID_of_button").click(function () {
  $('div_or_span_to_change').html('this will appear once you click the button');
});
</script>
```

I'm no expert though, so I'd need more info to give you an exact code to help you...hope this helps!

---

http://api.jquery.com/click/
http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: And, If you want to change the content onclick to other XML values, I'd suggest loading each language into a different variable, so that in the jquery you can just use php..
for instance  
`code
<script>
  $("Class_or_ID_of_button").click(function () {
  $('div_or_span_to_change').html('<?php echo $spanish?>');
});
</script>`